# How set horizontal scroll pane starting location on the right end?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a `JScrollPane` built like this:

```
JScrollPane scrollBar1 = new JScrollPane (tableForDay1, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

so that I can scroll up/down left/right.
and I want the scroller to start on the right when launching the application. It starts on the left by default.

how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: @Steve Would not that change the behavior too?

Comment: Hmm yeah - I guess you're right.

Comment: Thanks steve. that worked: scrollBar1.getHorizontalScrollBar().setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

Answer (score 1):

Given a JScrollPane you could get the horizontal scrollbar component (a JScrollBar) and then set its value to the maximum:

```
//renamed scrollBar1 because is a misleading name
JScrollPane scrollPane1= new JScrollPane (tableForDay1,
        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
        ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
JScrollBar horScrBar= scrollPane1.getHorizontalScrollBar();
horScrBar.setValue(horScr.getMaxValue());
```

Comment: (1+) but note that this code must be executed after the GUI is visible and there is no need for the "as needed" parameters since this is the default.